# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 Xcode unit tests

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, testing, target

I am getting this error when I try to run my unit tests. The entire error is:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageRelease", referenced from:
      _releaseImages in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
  "_CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex", referenced from:
      _delayCentisecondsForImageAtIndex in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
      _createImagesAndDelays in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateWithData", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(animatedGIF) animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:] in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateWithURL", referenced from:
      +[UIImage(animatedGIF) animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:] in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
  "_CGImageSourceGetCount", referenced from:
      _animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime", referenced from:
      _delayCentisecondsForImageAtIndex in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary", referenced from:
      _delayCentisecondsForImageAtIndex in UIImage+animatedGIF.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did all the instructions here:
http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/

Also added the library to "Compile Sources" in Build Phrases of the test target. Still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to add "CoreGraphics.framework" and "`ApplicationServices.framework`"  to your unit test target membership.

Here's how it's done for a file:

[image: Make sure Target Membership is selected for your .m file]

Just go to "CoreGraphics.framework" in the list of files and folders on the left side and make certain the checkmark is "ON" for the unit tests target.

Comment: Thank you this has only changed amount of errors from 9 to 8 by getting rid off the first one "_CGImageRelease". However I added all of my frameworks and it did work.

Comment: Ahh, yep... you also need to turn on the target membership for "`UIImage+animatedGIF.m`" as well.

Comment: make certain it's set for "`ApplicationServices.framework`", too.

Comment: Yeah! Sometime I'm using some file on other library but I have not add it!

Answer (score 1):

Go to build phases of target, Add **ImageIO.framework**